# Multiple side menus in Ionic 4 tab based app

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I've created a tabs based app with the command.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

The idea is to add different side menus for each tab pages, trying to do a master detail navigation, using the side menu as master elements list and the tab pages to show detailed content.

The `app.component.html` file looks like this:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

`tab1.page.html` like code:

```
<ion-menu contentId="aside1" side="start">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="side-menu-item" *ngFor="let item of strings">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet id="aside1" main></ion-router-outlet>
```

`tab2.page.html` code:

```
<ion-menu contentId="aside2" side="start">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="side-menu-item" *ngFor="let item of strings">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-router-outlet id="aside2" main></ion-router-outlet>
```

Both menus `aside1` and `aside2` works when I swipe and show the individual strings array elements at the first look of tabs. 
The problem is when I go back to previous tab, instead of show again `aside1 side menu`, this stop working and what the `swipe` gesture really does is show the side menu of the other tab.

I don't know if I need a particular code in `tab1.page.ts` and `tab2.page.ts` to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I haven't specify the `menuId` in each side menu.
For example:

```
<ion-menu contentId="main-content" menuId="main"> ... </ion-menu>

<ion-menu menuId="bar-menu"> ... </ion-menu>
```

I do not delete the question in case someone finds it interesting to create different menus for each page